# Minimal Latex Installation (<40 Mb) for Thesis?

Tags: windows, minimal

Are there any portable minimal latex distributions that use PDFLATEX for Windows (32 bits or 64 bits)?

I know of MikTeX portable for Windows, but about more than 130MBs. 
It is far from minimal.

The idea would be to be capable to build a PDF for a thesis or alternatively a simple article file (on latex).

To be ideally portable, <40Mb is great, since it can hold on a server such as GIT, SVN,... and you can work anywhere and anytime on your writing work.

Would you have any ideas?

thank you

Comment: it depends how many fonts and packages you "need" for your thesis. The first time I installed TeX it came on three 740K floppies but it didn't have tikz or unicode-math or ....

Comment: Use overleaf or sharelatex. They do storing for you, they even give you syntax highlighting, version control support and more.

Comment: Given that a multi-gig usb key can be had for a few dollars, why spend your time on this?

Answer (score 4):

If you want a small system, you'll need to 'roll your own': doable with both MiKTeX and TeX Live by hand. Probably best would therefore be to set something up as a portable install on one machine then zip all of that up.  The key to keeping something small is to skip retaining the sources and documentation: that tends to be bigger than working code.

TeX Live has a set of 'schemes' which one could use as a starting point beyond picking *everything* by hand. I do that for setting up automated testing: the [example for `siunitx`](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/blob/master/install.sh) is probably most useful. The approach there, which has a slightly different aim, is

- Install TeX Live using a profile that does the infrastructure only
- Add packages one at a time to make the code usable

For `siunitx`, which is set up to do tests with pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, the [Travis-CI testing system](https://travis-ci.org/josephwright/siunitx) tells me that the compressed size of the TeX system is currently about 30 Mb. (This is on a Linux system: see note below.)

The approach I'd take setting up TeX Live for 'day to day' typesetting in the same way would probably be

- Download the installer (http://tug.org/texlive) and run it manually
- De-select the installation of docs and sources
- Select the portable-style installation approach (and a suitable location)
- Select the 'basic' scheme, which includes plain TeX, the core of LaTeX and a small set of fonts
- Run the installer
- Do some tests and add any additional packages needed
- Zip up the installation and add store it as required

Using this approach I get a 76 Mb unpacked installation which shrinks to about 54 Mb on compression. I note that my `siunitx` archive is smaller as it was done entirely by hand: starting from just the TeX Live infrastructure and adding packages one at a time, but possibly lacking some material (it's only used automated testing not for looking at typeset output). (I also note that I've used `zip` to do some local 'test' compression whilst the Travis-CI setup probably uses a more efficient compression such as `.xz`.)

The sizes here are from an Ubuntu virtual machine: handy for setting up such tests and getting quickly back to a clean state. Using the suggested approach, including the 'normal' binaries, the `bin` subdirectory is by far the largest part of the install (46 Mb, x64), with the entire `texmf-dist` tree requiring only about 8 Mb. The balance is made up of local font caches, format files, *etc.*: if you want to keep a system small, select only the formats you use!

One could of course use much the same approach with MiKTeX, downloading the net installer and selecting a minimal number of packages: either way, there is a certain amount of manual work to do.

Comment: I've focussed on TeX Live here as this approach is usable cross-platform. Also, as it's therefore suitable for automated test environments, there've likely been more efforts to track down exactly how to minimise such set ups, when compared with MiKTeX.