# Update TeXLive from 2016 to 2018

Tags: texlive, debian, texlive-2017, texlive-2016, update

I have to update TexLive in order to use, at least, the 2017 version and I don't need the TexLive full version. The problem is that I'm using Debian 9.4 and the latest version available in the debian repository is TexLive-2016.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If you want a newer version that the one that is contained in the package repositories of your Linux distribution, I would recommend a vanilla installation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864

Comment: @moewe using the vanilla installation, is it possible to tell the installer the exact package you need, since I don't need the full TexLive? (And the full installation is quite huge)

Comment: There are installation schemes and you can select and deselect 'collections' of packages. You can install the smallest system possible and then add the packages you want with `tlmgr` later. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/352138/35864. It all depends on how minimal you want to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

meoewe solution works, see it in the comments or right below:

[Minimal Latex Installation (<40 Mb) for Thesis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/352138/35864)